# Adaptive Filter for Unknown-Frequency Noise

Tags: digital-filter

I am trying to design Adaptive filter for unknown frequency noise(jamming).

I want to design above filter as FIR based.

I've already search about LMS / RLS adaptive filter.

However I can't find any filter that for 'fully unknown frequency'.

(In most case, they need reference input that has same frequency with noise.)

Actually, I am CS major student and this field is not familiar with me.

I want to read many papers or books about it.

Can you recommend search keyword or topics for me?

Thank you.

Comment: So far you are interested in design of filter instead of implementation it with programming language in my opinion your question is off-topic.  I think http://dsp.stackexchange.com is more appropriate for such questions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't know about DSP stack exchange. I will try it.